# Hosting a blazor-hosted app with nginx and docker

Tags: c#, docker, nginx, asp.net-core, blazor

### Goal

Deploying/hosting a blazor-hosted (.Net Core 3 Preview 6) app on a Ubuntu server with a reserve-proxy (nginx) and docker (all containerized).

### Config Files

The dockerfile which got generated by Visual Studio:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Website.Server/Website.Server.csproj", "Website.Server/"]
COPY ["Website.Client/Website.Client.csproj", "Website.Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Website.Server/Website.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Website.Server"
RUN dotnet build "Website.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Website.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Website.Server.dll"]
```

The docker-compose.yml file which is used to launch the application:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
  wesbite:
    image: ImageToTheDockerFileAbove
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    restart: always
```

And finally my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   domain;
    
    location / {
        return 301 
        https://$host$request_uri;   
    }
}
server {
    listen        443 ssl;
    server_name   domain;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://website:80;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs of my ASP.Net Core app

```cs
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
            {
                opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                    new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseResponseCompression();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBlazorDebugging();
            }

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Startup>();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client.Startup>("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
```

### Problems

Actually there is just no content served at all and I am just getting a 404, but
the link between the container does exist. Since I can see the following output as soon as I type in my domain in the browser:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET domain  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'Fallback {*path:nonfile}'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'Fallback {*path:nonfile}'
```

Regarding to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/client-side?view=aspnetcore-3.0#hosted-deployment-with-aspnet-core) you are not required to add the following lines to the config of nginx, since the blazor app sits behind a normal ASP.Net Core application.

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
```

But when reading the error this still seems to me as a routing issue or similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Blazor in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847336/run-blazor-in-docker)

Comment: @codevision For some reason this didn't show up for me while searching for similar issues. Well but still this question is different, since it is a blazor-hosted application. Which I am not sure is the same for the linked post and additionally my Blazor App sits behind a reserve-proxy which is not the case for the post linked. Either way I will definitely try those things mentioned.

Comment: this exactly for Blazor-Hosted issue and you need "COPY" statement. When you do add COPY your issue will resolve. I forget to mention https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11185 in the original answer which contains additional hints for resolving. The problems still the same, incorrect routing to Blazor files which is resolved by manually copy published files to different location

Comment: Well If I add the COPY statement to my Dockerfile I tells me this directory or file does not exist. Even the `_content` folder does not seem to exist. I added the following line `COPY wwwroot/_content/ wwwroot/`, with `WORKDIR /app` above just to make sure. This is all below `RUN dotnet publish "Website.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app`.

Comment: Can you please run `dotnet publish` locally. If you examine content of published folder, very likely you see that you have to copy `wwwroot/_content/websiteclient` instead of `wwwroot/_content`

Comment: @codevision I understood that I need to copy the wwwroot folder, but it does not work, if you would read my last comment.